# How to make advanced search in windows using win32 api?

Tags: windows, winapi, search

I just stumbled upon a way to make advanced search in windows.
For instance, if I want to find files that starts with "f" I can type ctrl+f and `System.FileName  :~< “f”`

I was unable to find more information about this operator on the win32 api : `:~<`, or even anything about advanced search.

Could someone point me in the right direction please ?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should be asking this on SuperUser.SE.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/search-for-filenames-starting-with/c5b54309-0778-4f4e-8e28-a5ca739abea2

Comment: Incidentally, the only place where the syntax is documented is in the Windows Search Developer's Guide (see [Canonical Advanced Query Syntax in Windows 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-advancedquerysyntax#canonical-advanced-query-syntax-in-windows-7)).